# What is causing the realloc() invalid next size error?

Tags: c, pointers

I have to write a program that at first reads text from the user and separates that text into paragraphs, sentences and words. I have managed to get it working for small texts but for big ones i get an realloc() invalid next size error. I have managed to trace the block that cause the error but i can't figure out why it is caused. Here is the code
(https://gist.github.com/Kritsos/ed576224a36db0f68323bec6d541c286):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_special_char(char *A)
{
    int k, length, i;

    length = strlen(A);
    do
    {
        k = strcspn(A, ".,!?;");
        if(k != length)
            A[k] = ' ';
    }
    while(k != length);

    if(A[0] == ' ')
        for(i = 0;i < length;i++)
            A[i] = A[i + 1];

    for(i = 0;i < length;i++)
        if(!((A[i] >= 'a' && A[i] <= 'z') || (A[i] >= 'A' && A[i] <= 'Z')) && (A[i + 1] == ' ' || A[i + 1] == '\0'))
            for(k = i;k < length;k++)
                A[k] = A[k + 1];


}

int main()
{
    char **paragraphs = malloc(sizeof(char *)), **sentences = malloc(sizeof(char *)), **words = malloc(sizeof(char *)), *option;
    int num_par = 0, num_sent = 0, num_words = 0, i, quit = 0, count, length, j;

    if(paragraphs == NULL || sentences == NULL || words == NULL)
        return 1;

    do
    {
        option = malloc(10000 * sizeof(char));
        if(option == NULL)
            return 1;
        fgets(option, 10000, stdin);
        option[strcspn(option, "\n")] = '\0';
        length = strlen(option);
        option = realloc(option, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if(option == NULL)
            return 1;

        if(strstr(option, "ap:"))
        {
            //paragraphs
            num_par++;
            paragraphs = realloc(paragraphs, num_par * sizeof(char *));
            if(paragraphs == NULL)
                return 1;
            paragraphs[num_par - 1] = malloc((length - 2) * sizeof(char)); //length - 2 --> -3 ap: + 1 '\0'
            if(paragraphs[num_par - 1] == NULL)
                return 1;
            strcpy(paragraphs[num_par - 1], option + 3);
            remove_special_char(paragraphs[num_par - 1]);

            //sentences
            count = 0;//number of sentences
            for(i = 0;i < length;i++)
                if(option[i] == '.' || option[i] == '!' || option[i] == '?' || option[i] == ';')
                    count++;

            i = 3;
            while(count > 0)
            {
                num_sent++;
                sentences = realloc(sentences, num_sent * sizeof(char *));
                if(sentences == NULL)
                    return 1;
                sentences[num_sent - 1] = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
                if(sentences[num_sent - 1] == NULL)
                    return 1;

                j = 0;
                while(option[i] != '.' && option[i] != '!' && option[i] != '?' && option[i] != ';')
                    sentences[num_sent - 1][j++] = option[i++];
                i++;
                sentences[num_sent - 1][j] = '\0';
                sentences[num_sent - 1] = realloc(sentences[num_sent - 1], (strlen(sentences[num_sent - 1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                if(sentences[num_sent - 1] == NULL)
                    return 1;
                remove_special_char(sentences[num_sent - 1]);
                count--;
            }

  //THIS BLOCK RIGHT HERE CAUSES THE ERROR           
            //words
            count = 1; //number of words in paragraphs[num_par - 1] && words = spaces + 1
            length = strlen(paragraphs[num_par - 1]);
            for(i = 0;i < length;i++)
                if(paragraphs[num_par - 1][i] == ' ')
                    count++;

            i = 0;
            while(count > 0)
            {
                num_words++;
                words = realloc(words, num_words * sizeof(char *));
                if(words == NULL)
                    return 1;

                words[num_words - 1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
                if(words[num_words - 1] == NULL)
                    return 1;

                j = 0;
                while(paragraphs[num_par - 1][i] != ' ')
                    words[num_words - 1][j++] = paragraphs[num_par - 1][i++];
                i++;
                words[num_words - 1][j] = '\0';
                words[num_words - 1] = realloc(words[num_words - 1], (strlen(words[num_words - 1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                if(words[num_words - 1] == NULL)
                    return 1;
                count--;
            }
  //END OF FAULTY BLOCK
        }

        if(strstr(option, "qt"))
            quit = 1;
        free(option);

    }
    while(!(quit));

    //test
    for(i = 0;i < num_par;i++)
        printf("%s\n", paragraphs[i]);
    printf("--------------- %d\n",num_par);
    for(i = 0;i < num_sent;i++)
        printf("%s\n", sentences[i]);
    printf("--------------- %d\n",num_sent);
    for(i = 0;i < num_words;i++)
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    printf("--------------- %d\n",num_words);

    //memory leaks
    for(i = 0;i < num_par;i++)
        free(paragraphs[i]);
    free(paragraphs);
    for(i = 0;i < num_sent;i++)
        free(sentences[i]);
    free(sentences);
    for(i = 0;i < num_words;i++)
        free(words[i]);
    free(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Also i am sorry it is a bit difficult to read and follow. Here is the valgrind report:

```
==6252== Invalid read of size 1
==6252==    at 0x109033: main (main.c:112)
==6252==  Address 0x522fd66 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==6252==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6252==    by 0x108BEB: main (main.c:57)
==6252== 
==6252== Invalid read of size 1
==6252==    at 0x10900F: main (main.c:113)
==6252==  Address 0x522fd66 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==6252==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6252==    by 0x108BEB: main (main.c:57)
==6252== 
==6252== Invalid write of size 1
==6252==    at 0x109012: main (main.c:113)
==6252==  Address 0x522ffe2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 50 alloc'd
==6252==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6252==    by 0x108F91: main (main.c:107)
==6252== 
==6252== 
==6252== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==6252== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==6252== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==6252== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==6252== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==6252== 
==6252== 
==6252== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6252==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x562D000
==6252==    at 0x109012: main (main.c:113)
==6252==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6252==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6252==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6252==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6252==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6252== 
==6252== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6252==     in use at exit: 94 bytes in 7 blocks
==6252==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 6 frees, 11,342 bytes allocated
==6252== 
==6252== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6252==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6252==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6252==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6252==    still reachable: 94 bytes in 7 blocks
==6252==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6252== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6252== 
==6252== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6252== ERROR SUMMARY: 10000000 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: No i don't think so because if strcspn doesn't find what it's looking for it returns the length of the string.

Comment: What input do you type to trigger the crash?

Comment: That's the problem i don't know. The program works perfectly for eveyrthing i type in but i am supposed to submit it to a bot which automatically tests my code. There are 3 test cases (in which my code works fine) plus one hidden test case which probably has a big amount of input to test my memory allocation. My code crashes on the last test case and only shows me that a realloc() invalid next size error occured.

Comment: `char ** option; ... strlen(option)`  You probably meant to pass something different to strlen.

Comment: For starters, with `if(A[0] == ' ') ...A[i] = A[i + 1];`, `length` is never reduced before the next nested `for(i = 0;i < length;i++) ... for(k = i;k < length;k++) ...` set of loops. That could cause all sorts of havoc if you are off by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines look suspicious:

```
            while (paragraphs[num_par - 1][i] != ' ')
                words[num_words - 1][j++] = paragraphs[num_par - 1][i++];
```

It's not checking for the end of line condition.

Shouldn't it be this:

```
while ( (paragraphs[num_par - 1][i] != '\0') &&
        (paragraphs[num_par - 1][i] != ' '))
{
   words[num_words - 1][j++] = paragraphs[num_par - 1][i++];
}
```

Some general advice.  Your code goes way overboard with the amount of mallocs and reallocs.   There's more code dealing with memory management than there is actual program logic. And it leaves much to be desired wrt to formatting and style.  It would take a long time for me to write up how to improve it for readability and debuggability, but consider submitting it to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) after you get all the bugs out.

**Some more general advice**

Use curly brace blocks for all `if` and `for` blocks, even for "single lines".  Instead of this:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if (!((A[i] >= 'a' && A[i] <= 'z') || (A[i] >= 'A' && A[i] <= 'Z')) && (A[i + 1] == ' ' || A[i + 1] == '\0'))
        for (k = i; k < length; k++)
            A[k] = A[k + 1];
```

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (!((A[i] >= 'a' && A[i] <= 'z') || (A[i] >= 'A' && A[i] <= 'Z')) && (A[i + 1] == ' ' || A[i + 1] == '\0'))
    {
        for (k = i; k < length; k++)
        {
            A[k] = A[k + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Your `remove_special_char` function appears to just exist to remove punctuation chars from a string. It appears to do this by replacing all the punctuation chars with spaces.  Then removes all the spaces, then does some other double-nested for loop after that.  I think the entire function could be replaced as follows:

```
int isPunctuation(char c)
{
    return ((c == '.') || (c == ',') || (c == '!') || (c == '?') || (c == ';'));
}

void remove_special_char(char* str)
{
    char* ptrRead = str;
    char* ptrWrite = str;

    while (*ptrRead)
    {
        if (!isPunctuation(*ptrRead))
        {
            *ptrWrite = *ptrRead;
            ptrWrite++;
        }
        ptrRead++;
    }
    *ptrWrite = '\0';
}
```

You consistently reference array indices `number-1` and that makes your really hard to read.

```
 sentences[num_sent - 1][j++] = option[i++];
```

If you had just incremented `num_sent` after the fact, then your code would read as follows:

```
sentences[num_sent][j++] = option[i++];

// increment num_sent at the end of the loop
```

Further, don't increment index values while they are being used.  It's much harder to debug and read.  Better:

```
sentences[num_sent][j] = option[i];
i++;
j++;
```

Don't inline functions within functions such as the case here:

```
realloc(words[num_words - 1], (strlen(words[num_words - 1]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Better:

```
wordsize = strlen(words[num_words]) + 1;
words[num_words] realloc(words[num_words], wordsize * sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` I think is always 1 (at least in C++), but I digress.  But if you are expected to do that, write a helper function:

```
char* reallocateCharsForString(char* existing, size_t newlength)
{
    return (char*)realloc(existing, (newlength+1) * sizeof(char));
}
```

Now you got your `+1` and `sizeof(char)` nusances abstracted into a single function.  Now your allocation statements look much better:

```
wordlength = strlen(words[num_words]);
words[num_words] = reallocateCharsForString(words[num_words], wordlength);
```

You could do a similar abstraction for `malloc` as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much that was it. Unfortunately our professor for some reason tasked us with a string handling project in c (which doesn't even have a built-in string data type...) without telling us about structures, linked lists or buffer management and on top of that he said that our program will be tested on a very limited memory resources environment that's why EVERYTHING has to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: I just amended the answer to include some general code review advice that will improve the readability of your code. And if you improve the readability of code, you ultimately improve the ability to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(char)` is by definition 1;  It's better to write:

```
 words[num_words - 1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(*words[0]));
```

or given it's a buffer of bytes, just

```
 words[num_words - 1] = malloc(50);
```

---

There are many dangers in using `malloc()` and `realloc()` (especially with the latter):

- Both:  a reallocation of size 0 may return a non-NULL pointer that can't be dereferenced.  The only solution to this problem is to add a check for 0 before calling `*alloc()`.
- Both:  if the multiplication `nmemb * sizeof(*ptr)` would overflow, the resulting allocation will be smaller than expected, which will more than likely bite you.  A solution to that is [`reallocarray()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/reallocarray.3.html), which is present in some implementations (GLIBC and BSD at least).  Also `calloc()` (only solves `malloc()`) may be even safer for you if you use it for strings.  [`recallocarray()`](https://man.openbsd.org/recallocarray) would be even better, but is harder to find implementations using it.
- `realloc()`:  Asigning the result of `realloc()` without checking that it didn't fail will cause a memory leak when it fails.  A partial solution would be to use [`reallocf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/reallocf), although it may not be what you want.  It is present in BSD.  A better solution would be to add checks before the assignment.
- Both: If you don't check after the asignment if the pointer is non-NULL, your program will break if you try to dereference it.  The solution would be to write your own checks.